# Reduce the gap or white space between the title and 'hr' line using HTML

Tags: html, wordpress

Hopefully i've got the right bits in place prior to asking my question.

So basically im trying to figure out how to reduce the gap between title and the hr line using HTML instead of CSS.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: georgia, palatino, serif; font-size: 14pt;"><strong>What is?</strong></span></p>
```

the webpage is : https://nutreviva.com/peak-health-essentials/

Hopefully i have met the stack requirements, if not let me know exactly what i am doing wrong or missing out etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SouhailV said you should add margin top on **hr** element, but should also add **margin: 0;** to the previous **p** element:

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin: 0;">
```

Comment: Once I'm back at my laptop.... Possibly tomorrow evening I'll carry out your suggestions. I'm hoping to replace the CSS code with HTML directly in the text editor of each widget section. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: this completed the issue i was having, have to thank you both for your help. Highly appreciated, and learned something new in the process.

Answer (score 0):

try add style **margin-top: 5px;** to the **< hr>** like that :

```
<hr style="height: 5px;line-height: 300px;border: none;color: #1e73be;background-color: #1e73be;margin-top: 5px;">
```